# How do I select three images at random and then fade them out with a new image?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm mainly a PHP developer, and I haven't used jQuery or JavaScript in a long time.

I've looked on Google and on Stack Overflow but couldn't find the exact direction or code that I need to get the job done. Can anyone help?

I'm pulling in 12 random images via PHP and displaying them. I need to select three images at random every two seconds, fade them out, and have three new unique images fade back in, in their place.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
           <?php
              $logos = array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19');

              $randomize = array_rand($logos, 12);
              shuffle($randomize);
              foreach ($randomize as $randomize) {
                echo '<div class="col-3">';
                  echo '<img class="w-100 mt-4" src="assets/img/' . $randomize . '.png" alt="img">';
                echo '</div>';
              }
            ?>
```

Comment: keywords: "jQuery fadeIn", "jQuery fadeOut", "jQuery deferred objects" (or "jQuery animate callback")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replicate your array as a variable.

```
const logos = ['0', '1', '2', '3', ...];
```

> Quick tip, if the array values are sequential, i.e. 0-19, you can just do:
>
> `const logos = [...Array(19).keys()]`

Create a function that returns N random elements from the array. If you truly want unique randomisation then the examples on this site are plenty and you can use whatever tickles your pickle.

```
const randomize = (n) => logos.sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random()).slice(0, n);
```

Give your images a class to identify them i.e. `random-image`

```
<img class="w-100 mt-4 random-image" src="assets/img/12.png" alt="img">
```

Utilising jQuery's [`animate()`](https://api.jquery.com/animate/) method, you can fade out the existing image, change the image `src` by replacing the filename with the corresponding random array element, then fade in the image.

```
const images = $(".random-image");

let interval = setInterval(() => {
  let randomImages = randomize(images.length);
  images.each(function (index) {
    $(this).animate({opacity: 0}, 250, function () {
      this.src = this.src.replace(/(.*)\/.*(\.png$)/i, `$1/${randomImages[index]}$2`);
      $(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 250);
    });
  });
}, 2000);
```

The benefit of animating the opacity in place of the usual [fading methods](https://api.jquery.com/category/effects/fading/) is to retain document flow which will give you that "in-place" fade effect you desire. The `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods will actually change the `display` property of your elements which will make them disappear and interrupt the page flow.

---

Hope this jogs your memory a little.

Comment: Thank you, this is definitely a step in the right direction. Seems to only select the first three images of the page, they want any of the images on a 12 item grid to be randomly faded and the new images are not unique. Probably because they're being generated in PHP,

Comment: Quick edit here removes the `:lt(3)` and uses `images.length` to pass into `randomize()` which now also takes in a parameter to return the corresponding number of random elements. Glad it could help.